# Different approaches to scroll images?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-imageview, endlessscroll

What are the best approaches to easily scroll imageviews horizontally?

How can this be achieved without generating bitmap overflow memory exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do in this situation is draw the image three times, so you'd have a centre image and two next to it. Then, while it's scrolling, check if the view is entirely off of the centre image and if it is, reset the view coordinates to the same part of the image, only back on the centre one.
Image showing what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P18T2.png

EDIT: Can be done with only two images side by side, the third one is superfluous.

Comment: but then, i only need two images, but i dont like to have two bitmaps with the size of the screen in the memory at the same time... too munch bitmap memory

Comment: You don't need to keep two of the same image in memory, you could just draw the image, move it x amount of pixels right, draw again.

Comment: what? if you are moving the image to the left and you still dont have another second image in memory, you can't start drawin the second image on the right... so... two images in memory

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very much acquainted with android. What I offered is from my experience with OpenGL.

Comment: did you have code example of how to do this with android and opengl?

Comment: @AndroidUser99 Stefan is right, just call drawBitmap twice in your onDraw method

Comment: what do you mean with calling two times drawBitmap? Wich onDraw? ImageView onDraw? Wich drawBitmap? (there are seven drawBitmap options) and wich parameters should i use? please a little more explanation

Comment: snachmsm's answer there is exactly what I've been telling you to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create an endless circular ViewPager with only one item, and setting the image when the layout is instantiated. Also, override `destroyItem` in the adapter of the ViewPager and remove references of the Bitmap from the ImageView, to avoid memory leaks.